# Update To Sequelize-Typescript 5 causes exception "column createdAt does not exist"

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

After I updated Sequelize-typescript and Sequelize to version 5. I am keep getting error  "column createdAt does not exist", if I try to read anything from database. I don't have such column in my database and setup in my model.
I am using typescript experimental decorators.

```
import {Table, Column, DataType, PrimaryKey} from "sequelize-typescript";
import {Model} from "sequelize";
@Table({
    tableName: "SomeTable"
})
export class SomeModel extends Model<SomeModel> {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column({field: 'Column1', type: DataType.STRING})
    steemAccountName: string;

    @Column({field: 'Column2', type: DataType.FLOAT})
    sbdAmount: number;

    @Column({field: 'Column3', type: DataType.FLOAT})
    steemAmount: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I needed to set timestamps flag to false on my model declaration.

```
@Table({
    tableName: "SomeTable",
    timestamps: false
})
```